# Calculate the interpolation polynom with Neville scheme

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

i have the following:

$P \in \Pi_3$ is the interpolation polynom with $P(x_i)=f_i$, for
$$x_i \quad -1 \quad 0 \quad 1 \quad 3$$
$$f_i \quad 5 \quad -6 \quad -9 \quad 33$$
(table)

I want to calculate $P(2)$ with the Neville scheme.
But i dont get it how to do this.

Does anyone out here, know how to use the Neville scheme?
I tried to get it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am certain there are many ways to go about this but I shall do it by using this similarly to the Neville scheme by using the finite difference table to get the interpolating polynomial. Notice they give us $4$ points, so we are looking for a polynomial of degree $3$. Start by making your finite difference table:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|cccc}
x & y & & & & \\
\hline -1 & 5 &  & & \\
0 & -6 & & & \\
1 & -3&  & & \\
3 & 33 & & & & 
\end{array}
$$
and then fill it all out to get 
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|cccc}
x & y & & & & \\
\hline -1 & 5 & -11 & 4 & 1 \\
0 & -6 & -3 &8 & \\
1 & -3& 21 & & \\
3 & 33 & & & & 
\end{array}
$$
You should know how I obtained this. For example, the first row. I get the $-11$ by taking the first difference:
$$
\frac{-6-5}{0- (-1)}=\frac{-11}{1}=-11
$$
Then for the next column, you do the second difference:
$$
\frac{-3-(-11)}{1-(-1)}=\frac{8}{2}=4
$$
Following these shows you enough to create the whole table. The difference table gives us the interpolating polynomail:
$$
5+-11(x+1)+4(x+1)(x-0)+1(x+1)(x-0)(x-1)
$$
Exapnding this (though you don't have to), yields:
$$
p_3(x)=x^3+4x^2-8x-6
$$
Then $p_3(2)=2$, which is our approximation.

Comment: This is not what I get as a result.

Comment: @Amzoti Using the divided difference table? Mathematica confirms that using that method, the third degree polynomial approximation is the polynomial I obtained. If you are using Neville's scheme, then I'm not sure if this yields the exact same result. It has been awhile since my Numerical Analysis class and I cannot recall if it always yields the same approximation as the divided difference table.

Comment: Yes, the interpolation you did looks correct, but I get a different result using Neville's.

Comment: @Amzoti Then that is acceptable. Two different approximations don't have to yield the same result--pending that they don't differ by too much. Given we used different methods, it's not surprising we got different approximations.

Comment: They differ by a huge amount! Try your approach on these examples and see if you get the same result as Neville's http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~gli/math381lab5.pdf (there are two fully worked examples).